# Combining two curried functions

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Say we have two functions of type `(a -> b -> c)`. I want to have a single function, which, when applied to `a` and `b` will give `d`, merged from `c` by a specified function `(c -> c -> d)`. I came up with this solution using arrows:

```
combine :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> c) -> (c -> c -> d) -> (a -> b -> d)
combine f g op = ((uncurry op) .) . (uncurry (&&&)) . (f &&& g)
```

Is there a way to do this in more elegant way, or to generalize it to be applicable to functions with greater arity (e.g. `(a -> b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (d -> d -> e) -> (a -> b -> c -> e)`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't be afraid to be explicit. For me this is much easier to read:

```
combine :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> c) -> (c -> c -> d) -> (a -> b -> d)
combine f g op = \a b -> op (f a b) (g a b)
```

Doesn't look any uglier for more arities:

```
combine3 f g op = \a b c -> op (f a b c) (g a b c)
```

Comment: I think it would be even better with `op` as infix: ``f a b `op` g a b``. I suspect some people might disagree; part of it is that my editor highlights infix things differently which makes it much easier to read.

Comment: It's perfect, thanks! It always seems so easy when you already saw the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

While I agree the explicit lambda might be the way to go here, there are alternatives for binary `f` and `g`. For unary `f` and `g`, the solution is elementary.

```
combine f g op = liftM2 op f g
```

for binary `f` and `g`, we can make them unary by uncurrying them and then apply the same solution! This makes the binary version

```
combine2 f g op = curry $ liftM2 op (uncurry f) (uncurry g)
```

I'm just putting it out there as an alternative.

Comment: This is awesome.  Using `liftM2` on an operator to take advantage of functions `(->r)` as monads.  Brilliant!